# How can i set 132 Ppi resolution for new document in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, ios

I am using Illustrator CC and I need to create a document for iOS icons. How can I set, Illustrator only allows me to create 72ppi, 150ppi, or  300ppi.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The PPI is only for "raster effects" like drop shadow etc. You should leave it at 300PPI. Illustrator draws in vectors rather than pixels, so PPI for your actual icons is whatever you decide to export it at (pic)

[image]

Comment: When i exporting the image @132 ppi its getting double. not exact size as in document. Document size is in 300 ppi.

Comment: If you want your raster files at the exact pixel size you entered, you'll need to export at 72PPI. I believe these are the correct sizes:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Comment: @Praveenbg It's normal. Maybe you should read about resolution http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54995/why-does-photoshop-call-ppi-resolution/54996#54996. Also, you are creating something for iOS, in your case you might need to do some maths with the pixels instead of resolution if you work in Illustrator http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46689/how-to-prepare-what-all-sizes-and-resolutions-mockups-and-ui-graphics-for-an-a